# Support Audio/Video using Icelink and QB(Quick Blox) in Xamarin Forms App

Tags: xmpp, xamarin.forms, quickblox

I want to implement Audio & Video Calling using IceLink and QB(Quick Blox) in Xamarin forms app.

I have downloaded code from github - 
"https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-dotnet-sdk/tree/frozen-samples"

Login and user-list is successfully worked but when i have start video calling after selecting any user, it shows error:

> ```
> Not connected to XMPP server
> ```

As per my understanding, either

- `IceServer` is not connected or
- "`conference.RelayUsername`" or
- "`conference.RelayPassword`" is incorrect.

Right now, I have used -

```
private string[] IceServers =
{
"stun.l.google.com:19302",
"turn.quickblox.com",
"turn.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp",
"turn.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp",
"turnsingapor.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp",
"turnsingapore.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp",
"turnireland.quickblox.com:3478?transport=udp",
"turnireland.quickblox.com:3478?transport=tcp"
};

conference.RelayUsername = "test";
conference.RelayPassword = "pa55w0rd!";
conference.ServerPort = 3478;
```

So, please help me how to resolve this error and also provide support for Audio Calling.

Here's my output:

```
(13397): No SDP messages were received from the signalling server (the peer could not be reached).
(13397): No responses were received from the STUN/TURN server (the server could not be reached).
(13397): A remote offer/answer was not received!
(13397): No local candidates were created!
(13397): No remote candidates were received!
(13397): Link to peer is DOWN. Link timed out before a connection could be made. No SDP messages were received from the signalling server (the peer could not be reached). No responses were received from the STUN/TURN server (the server could not be reached).
(13397): Assembly Ref addref Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android[0xf4f172c0] -> System.Xml[0xd61e2a20]: 7
(13397): updateVisibility : ActivityRecord{8fc7e54 token=android.os.BinderProxy@7b7d6dc {com.quickblox.frozensample/md500fc13a2eac828e9753ec70581cd264d.MainActivity}} show : false
(13397): [0xd93de930] worker finishing
[0:] Not connected to XMPP server.
```